# Recommend- XORP vs GNU Zebra vs Quagga

Tags: networking, routing, quagga

Any recommendations which of [XORP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XORP), [GNU Zebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Zebra) and [Quagga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quagga_%28software%29) routing software is simple enough to hack and learn?

Answer (score 3):

Zebra seems to be dead, XORP, as far as I know, is not widely used in production environments.

I'm afraid you're left with Quagga.

Comment: +1 Zebra was unreliable anyway.

Comment: @David Pashley - so is quagga :/ very recently on debian there was glitch with handling as-paths containing multiple 32bit asns. http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=526270 besides - quagga dies for me once per month maybe. so i have [ as usual ] ugly watchdogs around it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *learn* routing as opposed to using in production, a mix of the Cisco emulator dynamips, and the Juniper "Olive" VM hacks gives you an amazing learning environment.

True, neither Cisco nor Juniper really approve of these, but they do work very well.

Comment: Olive: http://juniper.cluepon.net/index.php/Olive

Comment: GNS3 is a package that integrates a UI on top of the DynaMIPs engine; http://www.gns3.net/

Comment: Juniper "Olive", Cisco PIX and IDS also run in qemu pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much a recommendation, but a suggestion: [Bird](http://bird.network.cz/)