# Quagga vs XORP vs BIRD - linux BGP router recommendation

Tags: bgp

For a small multihomed network (/21) I am
researching possible bgp router software for linux. I found

- [Quagga](http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/),
- [XORP](http://www.xorp.org/) and
- [BIRD](http://bird.network.cz/)

and was wondering if

1. I have missed other recommendable bgp software for linux
2. anyone could speak in favour of or against any of these.

I know a [similar topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/33641/recommend-xorp-vs-gnu-zebra-vs-quagga) has been discussed bevor, but its been three years now, so the situation might have changed.

Comment: i'm afraid not much changed in the meanwhile but it'll be interesting to see the answers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_routing_platforms

Comment: wikipedia is the source of my research ... not all of them do bgp, not all of them are well supported on linux.

Comment: So, you can filter it :D

Comment: And in three years *this* question will be out of date...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XORP has a stable but rather dated BGP implementation.

Quagga, providing you actually use the latest available version (0.99.21 at the time of writing) that's on quagga.net it is generally reliable, featureful (now has working multipathing) and is easy to (re)configure while running.

BIRD also sports a good BGP implementation but can be a pain to administrate as reconfiguration requires editing the config files and instructing the daemon to reload it (either via a SIGHUP or birdc reload command)

As someone who likes the convenience of being able to reconfigure aspects of BGP quickly with minimal fuss, Quagga gets my vote - if this is of less concern to you, BIRD may still be of interest.